# How to get a random adjective or noun?

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, scripting, words

I did find a list of words in `/usr/share/dict/words` but I don't know if there's a way (an already existing way?) to split them up into their corresponding part of speech? Alternatively, I'm fine with any other suggestions, `/usr/share/dict/words` was only the first list of words I found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary api, I signed up for a free use token for merriam webster's dictionaryapi.com API.

Then you can get random words from the `/usr/share/dict/words` file (note on macos a lot of the words in this file are not actually real words, or not English words at least.).  Since that file doesn't contain any useful information about the word you then have to look it up using the api to find out if it's an adjective or a noun.

```
#!/bin/bash

token=get-your-own-token

until [[ $fl == noun || $fl == adjective ]]; do
    word=$(sort -R /usr/share/dict/words | tail -1)
    fl=$(curl -s "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/${word}?key=$token" | jq -r .[].fl 2>/dev/null)
done

echo "Word is: $word"
```

This is really slow (getting random words from the massive dict file on mac, not the API itself) because it usually has to find multiple words before it finds one that is a real word and is a noun or adjective.  Also in this code we are only looking at what part of speech the first definition of each word is, so it's possible that a word could be used as an adjective or noun but will be skipped because that isn't how the first definition of the word is used.

Eventually it does what you're looking for though but not well.

Comment: Hey thanks :) Sorry I didn't specify in the OP: I'm looking for an offline solution. That's the only reason why I mentioned `/usr/share/dict/words`. For example, I found the `scowl` package which says on its website http://wordlist.aspell.net/ "SCOWL (Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists) and Friends is a database of information on English words (...) The database primary contains information on (...) (basic) part-of-speech and (...)"

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make it work. I'm not depending on `scowl`, though, of course. But if I would be able to use an internet API, I would just request the noun/adjective from there without using `/usr/share/dict/words` at all. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off getting a taxonomically correct list of words to start with rather than trying to classify the list you have since people 'in the know' have already done the work.

Here's some from [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version) already classified as verbs, adjectives and nouns etc, though they don't seem to include participles, conjunctions etc etc.

The nouns `n`, verbs `v`, adverbs `r` and adjectives `a` are all in the index files with the identifying letter at the second field and so can be extracted with a little `awk`, passing them through `shuf` to randomise them and redirecting them to a file.

```
awk '{ if ( $2 ~ "^[nvar]$")  print $1" " $2 } ' index.* | shuf > mylist
```

This gives you a file of 155,339 words.

After that you can either pick a random line number or easiest just `shuf` the file and pick line 1 every time

```
shuf -n 1 mylist
```

Which will give you the word and the class

```
shuf -n 10 mylist

coolness n
coefficient_of_elasticity n
naive_realism n
flying_mare n
nut_bar n
santiago_de_chile n
turkmen a
fore-and-aft_topsail n
robert_gray n
follow_suit v
```

Some entries use "_" instead of a space so you will have to remove it if it offends.

To keep them separate ....

```
awk '{ if ( $2 ~ "^[nvar]$" )  {print $1 > "my"$2}} ' index.*
```

And your random word function could just be

```
shuf -n 1 my$1
```

Where you pass the class in as the argument (n, v, a or r) like

```
randword n
```

Comment: Not really but the file format is simple enough to `grep` or `awk` the word at a random line of your choice, The only tricky thing would be to use an appropriate weighting so that the proportion of returned results for each class is representative of their occurrence,  I would use the index files as a source and leave the others though this is just based upon my understanding that you want any old random word.....

Comment: Yup. Keep them offline as you wanted and index into them. Were you intending to guard against repetitions in your random selection?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I think I got the idea. Don't know yet how to do the grep/awk magic to get an actual random noun. No, I don't care about repetition. I'm looking for two simple scripts like `print_random_noun` and `print_random_adjective`.